# I can't get the col-8 to render side by side with col-4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Below is the code I submitted.

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-8">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="pic/Indian.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>
              This reciepie is called Tikka Masala, and its a fovrite in south India.
              The orgin of this dish is unkown to me, but I suppose that I can look
              into it and find out. When I go to Indian restaurants I always order
              this meal because its so good. I think that every one should try this
              food at some point in thier life and many will like it.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the part I need help with it does not seem to render correctly.

Comment: A row contains only 12 columns so when you try `col-8` and `col-md-8` the row will wrap the column. try `col-md-8` and `col-md-4`

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap number of columns are limited to 12. See the image below.

In your code you used following 2 line

```
<div class="col-8">
<div class="col-md-8">
```

That means you are acquiring 8 column first then another 8 column for next. Total 16 column. So to acquire another 8 column this is going to next row. If you want to solve this by limiting in one column, limit your column number by 12.

**Solution 1:**

```
<div class="col-8"></div>
<div class="col-4"></div>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks.

[image]